# If devices are registered in Intune, does configuration profile control the device's file associations or does the local device control it?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, adobe-acrobat, intune

I have a user which need to edit PDFs all the time. The user uses Adobe Acrobat. Somehow every day when the user tries to open a PDF, it randomly open in Chrome for some reason. This happens very randomly.

Once it opens fine with Adobe Acrobat, but then after don't know how many PDFs the user tries to open, it then switches to open in Chrome. The user does not change the setting to open in Chrome. This user is not alone, quite a few users have this problem (not all the users). Again very random with users who have the same problem.

We've tried all sort of ways that can fix the issue to stop opening PDFs with Chrome but no luck at all.

I noticed two things:

1. If people set PDF to open by default with Adobe Acrobat, regedit show this: `ProgID="AcroExch.Document.DC`. If I go to Default App in settings and select Chrome; then flip it to Adobe Acrobat, in regedit it changes to `Acrobat.Document.DC`
2. If I set Chrome to open PDFs in default app setting, it does open with Chrome. When I restart my laptop, it opens PDFs with Adobe Reader again.

Also I notice if the user installs Adobe Acrobat, Adobe Reader will auto uninstall. The Company Portal says it's required to install Adobe Reader, the event viewer says it cannot install, because a more powerful version is already installed.

Since all the devices are registered in Intune, I searched the web for 'file associations intune'. It comes with result Configuration profile. I log in to Intune and I find one profile said default apps. I reverse the base64 to xml file. It show this:

```
<Association Identifier=".pdf" ProgID="AcroExch.Document.DC" ApplicationName="Adobe Acrobat Reader DC" />
```

Now my question is does Intune control the device file association or is the device able to control its own default apps file association?

Comment: See [Manage File Type Associations via Intune](https://endpointcave.com/manage-the-file-type-associations-via-intune-part1/) and also see [Customizing the default app associations on Windows 11 devices](https://www.petervanderwoude.nl/post/customizing-the-default-app-associations-on-windows-11-devices/) and a note there: `Important: When customizing the default app associations, the existing associations of the user for the customized app associations will be overwritten.`

Comment: I edited your question for clarity. Please check the edit, and if I accidentally changed your meaning, please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1772624/edit) it yourself to correct any mistakes.

Comment: btw, we are using Windows 10 22H2, is that same with windows 11? Thank you

Comment: This configuration profile is deploy to everyone in my organisation. If I add a new group in excluded section, will the user in that group, are able to control their default app associations through default apps in Settings?

Answer (score 1):

*I'm putting this as an answer instead of comment, as the information is likely to be relevant for also others.*

You cannot have both 64-bit Adobe Reader and 64-bit Adobe Acrobat installed on the same system. Since Feb 2021 existing 32-bit Adobe Reader installations have been automatically and silently upgraded to 64-bit versions. This can be prevented by

1. Using an Enterprise or Federated ID to sign in to Acrobat Reader
2. Customizing Acrobat Reader using the Acrobat Customization Wizard and installing it
3. Installing third-party plugins
4. Disabling the automatic updates in Acrobat Reader

The 64-bit application is unified for Adobe Reader and Acrobat. The default install location in Windows is `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat`. If a 64-bit Reader is installed and user purchases an Acrobat subscription, the Reader will upgrade to fully functional Adobe Acrobat 64-bit application. Consequently it's not possible to have 64-bit Reader and Acrobat installed on the same system.

The automatic Reader 32-bit -> 64-bit upgrade can be prevented by editing the registry hive **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureLockDown**. Under this hive create new key **bUpdateToSingleApp**, choose Data type **REG_DWORD** and set its value to **0**.

Adobe Reader 32-bit for Windows can be downloaded from https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/acrobat-dc-downloads.html.

*Source: [Adobe Knowledgebase](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/about-acrobat-reader-dc-migration-to-64-bit.html)*

Answer (score 1):

Your company probably needs to move this setting to a new configuration profile that checks which ProgID needs to be set for `.pdf`, based on whether acrobat is installed:

- `ProgID="AcroExch.Document.DC"`: Adobe Reader
- `ProgID="Acrobat.Document.DC"`: Adobe Acrobat

Here's Adobe's list of IDs for different file types and versions (skip down to the tables):

- https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/pdfviewer.html#id1

---

You could exclude a specific group of users from this setting entirely or make an exclusion based on whether Acrobat is installed. Just make sure you're not excluding them from other settings they should be getting.